# Filtering months in angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Array which is linked to a dropdownlist

```
$scope.Months =
    [
        {
            Name: "Month",
            Value: undefined
        },

        {
            Name: "Jan",
            Value: 1
        },

        {
            Name: "Feb",
            Value: 2
        },

        {
            Name: "Mar",
            Value: 3
        },

        {
            Name: "Apr",
            Value: 4
        },

        {
            Name: "May",
            Value: 5
        },

        {
            Name: "Jun",
            Value: 6
        },

        {
            Name: "Jul",
            Value: 7
        },

        {
            Name: "Aug",
            Value: 8
        },

        {
            Name: "Sep",
            Value: 9
        },

        {
            Name: "Oct",
            Value: 10
        },

        {
            Name: "Nov",
            Value: 11
        },

        {
            Name: "Dec",
            Value: 12
        }
    ];
```

Then I receive an array of data:

```
$scope.Data = 
[
{
Name: "Example Jan", 
Month: 1
},
{
Name: "Example Jan2", 
Month: 1
},
{
Name: "Example Feb", 
Month: 2
},
{
Name: "Example Feb2", 
Month: 2
},
{
Name: "Example Nov", 
Month: 11
},
{
Name: "Example Nov2", 
Month: 11
}
]
```

The thing here is that whenever you select a Month in the DDL, it should only display the DATA to which the month belongs... For instance... Select November, it should display all Data which the Value of Month equals 11...

But I noticed that when you select January for example, it will display all Data that contains 1 in it's value.. in this case, 1 and 11.

Considering it's an int instead of a string, is there a work around this?

UPDATE:
This is my HTML

```
<table class="submitted-requests sortableTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-click="Sort('Supervisor.Name')">
                                <span>
                                    Supervisor
                                </span>

                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="SortKey=='Supervisor.Name'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':Reverse, 'glyphicon-chevron-down':!Reverse}">
                                </span>
                            </th>

                            <th ng-click="Sort('ObservationDateString')">
                                <span>
                                    Observation Date
                                </span>

                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="SortKey=='ObservationDateString'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':Reverse, 'glyphicon-chevron-down':!Reverse}">
                                </span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <input type="text" class="filter" maxlength="50" ng-model="SearchTerm.Supervisor.Name" />
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                <select class="filter" ng-options="month.Value as month.Name for month in Months track by month.Value" ng-model="SearchTerm.ObservationMonth"></select>

                                <select class="filter" ng-model="SearchTerm.ObservationYear">
                                    <option ng-repeat="year in Years | orderBy: 'year.Value'" value="{{year.Value}}">
                                        {{year.Name}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr dir-paginate="record in Records | filter:SearchTerm | itemsPerPage:PageSize" pagination-id="recordPaging">
                            <td>
                                {{record.Supervisor.Name}}
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                {{record.ObservationDateString}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <dir-pagination-controls pagination-id="recordPaging" max-size="10" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true">
                </dir-pagination-controls>
```

and aditional data:

```
$scope.Records = 
[
    {
        Supervisor: 
        {
            Name: "Julio"
        }, 
        ObservationDateString: "01/14/2015",
        ObservationDateMonth: 1,
        ObservationDateYear: 2015
    },
    {
        Supervisor: 
        {
            Name: "Julio"
        }, 
        ObservationDateString: "02/16/2015",
        ObservationDateMonth: 2,
        ObservationDateYear: 2015
    },
    {
        Supervisor: 
        {
            Name: "Gaspar"
        }, 
        ObservationDateString: "11/11/2015",
        ObservationDateMonth: 11,
        ObservationDateYear: 2015
    },
    {
        Supervisor: 
        {
            Name: "Erik"
        }, 
        ObservationDateString: "12/05/2014",
        ObservationDateMonth: 12,
        ObservationDateYear: 2014
    },
]

$scope.Year =
[
    {
        Name: "Year",
        Value: undefined
    },

    {
        Name: "2014",
        Value: 2015
    },

    {
        Name: "2014",
        Value: 2015
    },

    {
        Name: "2016",
        Value: 2016
    }
];
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML markup?

Comment: done... I updated the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a custom filter function, and use it when you call your filter. Something like this:

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentMonth = 1;
  $scope.Data = [];

  $scope.monthMatch = function(month) {
    return function(item) {
      return item.Month == month;
    };
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in Data | filter:monthMatch(currentMonth)">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</body>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tfo8ux32/

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work out... not sure if it has to do with the multiple filtering options that I have... or if I was missing something while testing.

I've updated my post, probably I was missing something on the first show.

Comment: I've added a working fiddle, maybe it will assist you in finding the problem.